# Change last octet of IP returned by gethostentry

Tags: c#, split, ip-address

Was wondering if anyone could help me out here. I don't dont much with c# but its easy for what im trying to do.

I am making a small application that will take in the hostname on my network and then return the full ipaddress(ipv4) ....From there i have options to ping/vnc/telnet...etc.

My question lies here... I am using `GetHostEntry` to return the ip address. Then I want to store the IP into a variable, and change the last octet. I figured a simple `sting.split('.')` would be the answer, but I can't convert the IP to a string because the source is not a string. Any ideas?

Here is my Method to get the IP address, its just the basic `GetHostEntry` method:

```
IPHostEntry host = Dns.GetHostEntry( hostname );

Console.WriteLine( "GetHostEntry({0}) returns: {1}", hostname, host );

// This will loop though the IPAddress system array and echo out
// the results to the console window

foreach ( IPAddress ip in host.AddressList )
{
    Console.WriteLine( "    {0}", ip );
}
```

Comment: (1) GetHostEntry() is obsolete (2) based on your requirement, GeHostEntry() may not be the method that you want - the AddressList returns a list IP addresses for a given hostname.

Comment: How cute I was. :) Botonomous 2016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a rather brittle method that relies on the byte order of your machine and, obviously, the family of the provided address.

```
byte[] ipBytes = ip.GetAddressBytes();
while (ipBytes[0]++ < byte.MaxValue)
{
  var newIp = new IPAddress(ipBytes);
  Console.WriteLine("    {0}", ip);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is only one network adapter:

```
// When an empty string is passed as the host name, 
// GetHostEntry method returns the IPv4 addresses of the local host
// alternatively, could use: Dns.GetHostEntry( Dns.GetHostName() )
IPHostEntry entries = Dns.GetHostEntry( string.Empty );
// find the local ipv4 address
IPAddress hostIp = entries.AddressList
                  .Single( x => x.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork );
```

Once you have the host IP, you can then use the IP bytes to create a new IP address by modifying any of the octets. In your case, you're wanting the last octect to be modified:

```
// grab the bytes from the host IP
var bytes = hostIp.GetAddressBytes();
// set the 4th octect (change 10 to whatever the 4th octect should be)
bytes[3] = 10;
// create a new IP address
var newIp = new IPAddress( bytes );
```

Of course, you can change any of the octets. The above example is only for the 4th octet. If you wanted the first octet, you'd use `bytes[0] = 10`.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it to a string by using the IPAddress object's ToString() method.

Have you considered just using the System.Net.IPAddress object?

Here is the document on its Parse method, which takes a string and attempts to convert it to an IPAddress object, so you could do whatever string magic you wanted to do: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.parse.aspx

Or, if you want to know how to convert a string to a number, try the numeric data type's TryParse method. Perhaps Int32.TryParse would work.